# Getting error while migrating code from svn to git repository: Malformed network data: The XML response contains invalid XML: svn2git

Tags: git-svn, svncommit

Ran command git svn clone "SVN URL".

It works fine till 4568 commits, but then it gets after this commit giving the error stated in title.

Comment: The exact error that we get is Malformed network data: The XML response contains invalid XML: Malformed XML: no element found at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 312.

Comment: Do you use git-svn as a frontend for an eixisting SVN repository that remains exisiting or do you try to do a one-time conversion of an SVN repository to Git?

Comment: @Vampire Can you please clarify your statement.

Comment: What is unclear? Do you have an SVN repository that will still hold the canonical state of your source or do you try to do a one-time conversion of an SVN repo to a Git repo and are using Git exclusively from there on.

Comment: One time conversion. After this we will freeze our son repo. We are using git svn command to do this. @Vampire

Answer (score 3):

this seems to be because the default `log-window-size` is too small.

When you get error, from the new git repo, try running:
`git svn fetch --log-window-size=4000`

You can experiment with the actual number, but `4000` was the magic number for me.

Comment: Same with --log-window-size=100000

Comment: In my case when I create svnadmin dump
svnadmin: E160004: Filesystem is corrupt
svnadmin: E200014: Checksum mismatch while reading representation:
   expected:  b564bb2bc05a87375cb56817aaca060f
     actual:  37ed90170516d2c16cc6976c86597150

Answer (score -3):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.